# Upgrading to Struts 2.3.32. Getting System Error from org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil

Tags: struts2, tiles, websphere-7

I am upgrading an existing App to `Struts 2.3.32` and when I add the App to a `WebSphere 7.0` server I get the following error.

```
[3/14/17 16:02:22:200 CDT] 00000009 SystemErr     R 110 [Default : 2] INFO org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil - Publishing TilesContext for context: com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.facade.ServletContextFacade
[3/14/17 16:02:22:293 CDT] 00000009 SystemErr     R 203 [Default : 2] INFO org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess - Publishing TilesContext for context: org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext
```

The app appears to be running correctly.  Are these errors just informational or do I need to fix them?  The jar files included in my `WEB-INF` are

[image]

Comment: `INFO` It is an info.

Answer (score 0):

Use these jars:

struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.1.2.jar

tiles-servlet-2.1.2.jar

Hope this will help.

Comment: No, it isn't helpful. How does it answer OP question?